# Add delays to Google Home routines

Tags: smart-home, google-home, smart-assistants

I have a new Google Home Mini and I'm looking to add a lot of customization to it and the devices connected to it. The built in "routines" seems quite limited, the main thing I want to do is add delays into the routines but this is not a built-in function.

I'm looking for a tool that would allow me to do add more customization especially delays.  I'm a software developer so I'm open to programming or messing with config files but the simplest solution/tool would be best. As far as I can tell IFTTT does not have the tools to do what I want with my products.

Here is an example of what I would like to do. I know how to do all of this except the delays.

Example routines:

- turn light to yellow
- turn light to 20% brightness
- set volume to 10%
- play podcast
- **wait 10 min**
- set light to 15% brightness
- set light to orange
- **wait 10 min**
- set light to 10% brightness
- set light to red
- **wait 10 min**
- set light to 5% brightness
- stop podcast
- start white noise

---

My system and tools at my disposal:

- Google Home Mini.
- Merkury Smart Wi-Fi LED Bulb Color.
- Android phone.
- Windows 10 desktop.

Comment: Jeff, you probably don't have the rep to see it, but user @MarkPalmos posted an answer which was deleted because it was link only. If he edits it to include an answer, not just a link (because links can rot), you will be able to see it, and to award it the answer, if you like it. Meanwhile, in case it helps, his link was https://www.push2run.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=948&p=2257#p2257

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google finally added this as part of the home assistant app! It's now a default function.

If you need a full guide with pictures I'll link some below. But simply put all you need to do is when you are making a routine add a new action, at the bottom of the list of action there is an "add delay" button. Just select this and set the time you want your delay to last. Then add the action you want to happen after the delay. You can repeat this to add as many actions and delays as you would like (there is likely some limit).

Here are some detailed guides:

- [9to5google: How to set up delayed actions in Google Home’s Assistant Routines](https://9to5google.com/2022/03/31/how-to-set-up-delayed-actions-in-google-homes-assistant-routines/#:%7E:text=a%20Voice%20command.-,Setting%20up%20delays,on%20the%20counter%2C%20tap%20Done.)
- [how to geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/794085/how-to-add-a-delay-to-google-assistant-routines/)